# Spree Payment Checkout API Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, spree, spree-auth-devise

When I try to make an payment for particular order in the payment state by sending this PUT request to

```
PUT /api/checkouts/:number.json
```

With this json

```
{ order: { "payment_attributes": [ { "payment_method_id": 2 } ], "state": "payment", "use_existing_card": "no" } }
```

I get this error exception

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

and this is log

```
2015-10-09T13:29:59.568835+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: f07d385a-feeb-4df3-86e9-75fde134917c) to Inline(mailers) with arguments: "Spree::OrderMailer", "confirm_email", "deliver_now", 364
2015-10-09T13:29:59.577417+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [f07d385a-feeb-4df3-86e9-75fde134917c]   Spree::Order Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "spree_orders".* FROM "spree_orders" WHERE "spree_orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 364]]
2015-10-09T13:29:59.580871+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
2015-10-09T13:29:59.586799+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 857ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 334.6ms)
2015-10-09T13:29:59.523283+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "spree_payments".* FROM "spree_payments" WHERE "spree_payments"."order_id" = $1 AND ("spree_payments"."state" NOT IN ('failed', 'invalid'))  ORDER BY spree_payments.created_at  [["order_id", 364]]
2015-10-09T13:29:59.550332+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (3.3ms)  UPDATE "spree_orders" SET "payment_state" = $1, "shipment_state" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "spree_orders"."id" = $4  [["payment_state", "balance_due"], ["shipment_state", "pending"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-09 13:29:59.538550"], ["id", 364]]
2015-10-09T13:29:59.559930+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.5ms)  BEGIN
2015-10-09T13:29:59.568004+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.8ms)  COMMIT
2015-10-09T13:29:59.571496+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [f07d385a-feeb-4df3-86e9-75fde134917c] Performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Inline(mailers) with arguments: "Spree::OrderMailer", "confirm_email", "deliver_now", 364
2015-10-09T13:29:59.578783+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [f07d385a-feeb-4df3-86e9-75fde134917c] 
2015-10-09T13:29:59.578786+00:00 app[web.1]: Spree::OrderMailer#confirm_email: processed outbound mail in 3.4ms
2015-10-09T13:29:59.580392+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [f07d385a-feeb-4df3-86e9-75fde134917c] Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Inline(mailers) in 5.56ms
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581859+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/spree-multi-domain-93fc80961817/app/mailers/spree/order_mailer.rb:6:in `confirm_email'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581862+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581864+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581865+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581867+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581868+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581869+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581871+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581872+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581874+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:596:in `block in process'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581875+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581877+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581878+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581879+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:593:in `process'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581880+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:584:in `initialize'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581881+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:25:in `new'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581882+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:25:in `__getobj__'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581884+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:34:in `message'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581885+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:85:in `deliver_now'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581886+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/delivery_job.rb:10:in `perform'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581887+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/execution.rb:32:in `block in perform_now'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581888+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581890+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581891+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581892+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581893+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581895+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in around'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581896+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581897+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581899+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:257:in `with_locale'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581900+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/translation.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Translation>'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581901+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581903+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581904+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581905+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `block in simple'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581907+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581908+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581913+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581914+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581915+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in around'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581968+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Logging>'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581969+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `block in tag_logger'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581971+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581972+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581973+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581974+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `tag_logger'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581976+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Logging>'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581977+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581978+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581980+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581981+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `block in simple'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581987+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581988+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581990+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581991+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581992+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581994+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_enqueue_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581995+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581996+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:67:in `enqueue'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581998+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/configured_job.rb:13:in `perform_later'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.581999+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:112:in `enqueue_delivery'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582001+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:68:in `deliver_later'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582002+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spree_core-3.0.4/app/models/spree/order.rb:359:in `deliver_order_confirmation_email'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582003+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spree_core-3.0.4/app/models/spree/order.rb:347:in `finalize!'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582005+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/eval_helpers.rb:58:in `evaluate_method'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582006+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/callback.rb:192:in `block in run_methods'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582007+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/callback.rb:191:in `each'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582008+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/callback.rb:191:in `run_methods'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582010+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/callback.rb:159:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582011+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:394:in `block (2 levels) in after'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582012+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:394:in `each'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582013+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:394:in `block in after'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582014+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:392:in `catch'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582018+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:392:in `after'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582020+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:195:in `run_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582021+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:127:in `run_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582022+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582024+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:63:in `catch'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582025+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block in perform'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582026+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:186:in `within_transaction'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582027+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:62:in `perform'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582028+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:163:in `perform'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582029+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/event.rb:155:in `fire'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582031+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/event.rb:219:in `block in add_actions'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582032+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/machine.rb:725:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582033+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/machine.rb:725:in `block (2 levels) in define_helper'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582034+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spree_api-3.0.4/app/controllers/spree/api/checkouts_controller.rb:38:in `update'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582035+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582037+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582038+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582039+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582040+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582041+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582042+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582044+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582045+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582046+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582047+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582048+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582049+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582051+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582052+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582053+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582054+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582055+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582056+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582058+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582060+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582063+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582065+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582066+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582067+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582068+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582069+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582070+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582072+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582073+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582074+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582075+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582076+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582078+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582079+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582080+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582081+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582083+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582084+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582085+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582086+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582087+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582088+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582090+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582091+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582092+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582093+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582095+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582096+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582097+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582098+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582099+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582101+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582102+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582103+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582104+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582106+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582107+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582108+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582109+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582113+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582114+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582116+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582117+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582118+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582119+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582120+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582121+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582123+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582124+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582125+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582126+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582127+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582128+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582130+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582131+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582132+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582133+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582135+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582136+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582137+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.582138+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
2015-10-09T13:29:59.583078+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered text template (0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure but my expected guess is that your payment method is not defined and instance that is supposed to contain it is nil and when code is trying to get name attribute on this instance, it gives error because object itself is nil.

You can find it exactly by debugging and seeing the state of your variables.